# Algorithms for Unitary Representations of Finite Groups

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, representation-theory

Given a $d$-dimensional $\mathbb C$-linear representation of a finite group $G$, *i.e.* $\pi \!: G \to \mathrm {GL}_d(\mathbb C)$, one can use [Weyl's unitary trick](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/weyl-s-unitarity-trick) to construct an inner product $\langle v, w\rangle_\mathrm U$ for $v, w \in \mathbb C^d$ under which that representation is unitary.  To do so, one begins an arbitrary inner product $\langle v, w\rangle_a$, such as the trivial $\langle v, w\rangle_1 = v^\dagger w$, and calculates
$$ \langle v, w\rangle_\mathrm U = \frac 1 {|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \left \langle \pi (g) v, \pi(g) w \right \rangle_a. $$
Now, $\forall g,\,v \! : \, \langle \pi(g) v, \pi(g) v\rangle_\mathrm U = \langle v, v\rangle_\mathrm U$.

Naïvely, evaluating such an inner product requires $O(d^3|G|)$ multiplications, which quickly becomes infeasible for non-trivial representations of interesting groups.  Can anyone suggest a way to use the group structure to reduce the $|G|$ factor in the complexity of this algorithm?  Alternatively, any efficient way to calculate an equivalent representation which is unitary under the trivial inner product $\langle v, w\rangle_1$, so $\forall g \! : \, \pi(g) \in \mathrm U(d)$, would suit my needs as well.

Comment: How is the representation given? Is it a concrete list of matrices, or is there a function with some considerable running time which can act by $\pi(g)$ on a vector? My immediate approach would be to use the naive version of the inner product and apply the Gram-Schmidt process to get an orthonormal basis: that basis gives you a conjugating matrix $T$ such that $T \pi(g) T^{-1}$ is unitary, and after that point evaluating inner products becomes $O(d)$.

Comment: @Joppy I happened upon a similar process and began writing it up as an answer as you posted your comment.  How could we use a single $\pi(g)$ to construct an orthonormal basis?  I'm unclear how one could use Gram–Schmidt with the naïve inner product to produce anything non-trivial.  And surely if $g$ were the identity element, $\pi(g)$ would be the identity matrix, and nothing would be gained.

Comment: By "the naive version of the inner product" I did mean summing over all group elements - there is little chance that you could get a $G$-invariant inner product by only considering a single $\pi(g)$. The reason I was asking about how the representation is given is because a lot depends on that: do you have a list of matrices, or a function which can act on a vector, or a function that returns a whole matrix, etc... I'm glad you managed to find a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question less than twenty-four hours after posting it, but I've found a solution.  Using a small number of group elements $g_1, \ldots g_n \in G$ and the standard orthornormal basis $\mathbf B = \left [ \mathbf e_j \in \mathbb C^d \! : \, j \in 1, \ldots, d \, \right ]$, one can construct constraints on a satisfactory inner product $ \left \langle \pi \! \left ( g_i \right ) \mathbf e_j, \pi \! \left ( g_i \right ) \mathbf e_k \right \rangle_\mathbf U = \left \langle \mathbf e_j, \mathbf e_k \right \rangle_\mathbf U$.

In my test case, the two non-orthogonal generators $g_1$ and $g_2$ of [a 20-dimensional $\mathbb R$-linear representation of the $\mathrm M_{11}$ sporadic group](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/matrep/M11G1-Zr20B0) (of orders two and four, respectively) were sufficient to solve for the real symmetric matrix elements of a satisfactory inner product, up to normalization.

From there, one can perform a change of basis on $\pi$ from an orthonormal basis (*e.g.* constructed using the Gram–Schmidt process) with respect to $\langle v, w \rangle_\mathbf U$ to the standard basis $\mathbf B$, which is orthonormal with respect to the trivial inner product $\langle v, w \rangle_1 $, to get a representation which is in $\mathbf U(d)$.

**Update:$\:$** The rank of the constraints from $g_1$ alone is 96, while that of $g_2$ is 154.  Together, they get 209 of the $210 = d(d + 1)/2$ independent matrix elements of the unitary inner product, leaving only the normalization unfixed.

**Update 2:$\:$**  From my "simple" $\mathrm M_{11} \! \to \mathrm{SL}_{20}(\mathbb R)$ test case, it seems like the constraint ranks are a function of the element's conjugacy class.  I calculated:

- $\hphantom{1} 1A \hphantom{/B} : \: \: \hphantom{00} 0$
- $\hphantom{1} 2A \hphantom{/B} : \: \: \hphantom{0} 96$
- $\hphantom{1} 3A \hphantom{/B} : \: \: 138$
- $\hphantom{1} 4A \hphantom{/B} : \: \: 154$
- $\hphantom{1} 5A \hphantom{/B} : \: \: 168$
- $\hphantom{1} 6A \hphantom{/B} : \: \: 170$
- $\hphantom{1} 8A/B : \: \: 182$
- $11A/B : \: \: 190$

I was, unfortunately, unable to relate to relate these values to the character table in any meaningful way, although they seem like a somewhat interesting, albeit representation-dependent, "class function", in the group-theoretic sense.

**Update 3:$\:$**  My method takes about a minute for representations to $\mathrm {GL}_{77} (\mathbb Z)$.  Meanwhile, for [a 77-dimensional, absolutely irreducible, $\mathbb Z$-linear representation](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/matrep/J1G1-Zr77aB0) of the [sporadic, pariah, finite simple group $\mathrm J_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janko_group_J1), [Magma's](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) [`InvariantForms`](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/704#8161) finds an valid inner product in $80\,\mathrm {ms}$.  As their software is closed source, I don't know what algorithm they're using.  I'll have to do more research regarding invariant forms.  I've also contacted Magma's developers for a mostly unrelated reason, but included a side-question asking how the `InvariantForms` function works.

Any further insight would be appreciated.